# Bones move from their initial position after adding IK elbow pole

Tags: rigging

after adding an elbow IK pole to the arm it shifts from its original position i wonder what the cause of this issue is
i also made sure to clear parent and disconnect the elbow bone too
i also deleted the pole bone and readded it again and same issue

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour: the angle of the IK chain always points at the pole bone.

To solve, trim the pole angle value in the IK constraint panel and/or pole bone location (in edit mode) so that the shift between edit mode and pose mode is minimum or null.